# Gradient Descent in Python 3

Tags: python, numpy

I have a code Gradient Descent in Python 3 and error appear I do not know how I can solve it ...

and I have a question why the result of the dataset give me a zero for accuracy anyone can help me, please  :(

I try to change some things but no benefit.

I divide my dataset into two parts for the training set and for the test set

```html
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N_EPOCHS = 10
LEARNING_RATE = .1
PLOT = False
LAMBDA = .00000001

def load_data(filename):
    X = []
    Y = []


    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        X = [[float(x) for x in line] for line in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')]

        for line in X:
            Y.append([line[-1]])
            line.pop()

        print(X[0])
        print(Y)

    X = np.array(X, dtype=np.longdouble)
    Y = np.array(Y, dtype=np.longdouble)
    return X, Y

def sigmoid(weight_param, x_param):
    denom_sigmoid = np.longdouble(1 + np.exp(np.dot(-weight_param, x_param)))
    sig = np.longdouble(np.divide(1, denom_sigmoid, where=denom_sigmoid!=0.0))
    return sig

def gradient_descent(X, Y, L2_Regularization=False):

    example_accuracy = []
    X = np.c_[np.ones((X.shape[0])), X]  # Add bias of 1 to each example
    feature_len = X.shape[1]
    example_count = np.long(X.shape[0])
    print("X.shape ", X.shape)
    # Random weight vector with shape equal to number of features
    w = np.zeros(feature_len)
    l2_reg = 0
    step = 0
    correct_count = 0
    while(step < N_EPOCHS):
        print("Iteration: ", step)
        grad = np.zeros(feature_len, dtype=np.float)
        for example in range(example_count):
            # y_hat is the predicted output
            y_hat = sigmoid(w.T, X[example])
            if L2_Regularization:
                l2_reg = LAMBDA * w  # = d/dw(.5*lambda*||w^2||)

            if y_hat >= .5:
                y_hat = 1
            loss = y_hat - Y[example]
            if loss[0] == 0:
                correct_count += 1
                print(correct_count)
            grad += loss[0] * X[example] + l2_reg

        w += -LEARNING_RATE * grad

        step += 1
        example_accuracy.append(np.float(correct_count / example_count))
        correct_count = 0


    print(" Accuracy per Epoch: ", example_accuracy)

    return w, example_accuracy

def main():

    X, Y = load_data("/Users/mahaalmotiri/PycharmProjects/desktop/GradientDescent /data.csv")
    X_test, Y_test = load_data("/Users/mahaalmotiri/PycharmProjects/desktop/GradientDescent /data2.csv")

    w, example_accuracy = gradient_descent(X, Y)
    epoch_list = [epoch for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS)]
    if PLOT:
        plt.plot(epoch_list, example_accuracy)
        plt.xlabel('Epoch')
        plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
        plt.show()

    w_L2_train, example_accuracy_L2_train = gradient_descent(X, Y, L2_Regularization=True)
    w_L2_test, example_accuracy_L2_test = gradient_descent(X_test, Y_test, L2_Regularization=True)
    print("Example accuracy no L2_Regularization: ", example_accuracy)
    print("example_accuracy_L2_train: ", example_accuracy_L2_train)
    print("example_accuracy_L2_test: ", example_accuracy_L2_test)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

error is [image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Next time you post a question, keep your error message as text instead of as an image as found in ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This warning means that degree `np.dot(-weight_param, x_param)` is too big here:

```py
denom_sigmoid = np.longdouble(1 + np.exp(np.dot(-weight_param, x_param)))
```

so you get large number after computing exponent in the degree.

If you want to get rid of this you just need to make it smaller. Maybe you want to normalize you input data using [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html).

Comment: can you help me to write normalize code because I do not know how I can write it and if need import certain packages ??

Comment: [this example should be a good start](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#standardization-or-mean-removal-and-variance-scaling)